# Azure IoT Edge - Deploy & Debug Module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge

I'm building a module with nodejs to run inside Azure IoT Edge V2. For this I have set up the runtime on a Raspberry Pi running in my local network.
I'm following [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module#debug-a-module-with-the-iot-edge-runtime) and was able to reproduce all previous steps until **Debug a module with the IoT Edge runtime**.

I get a success response after both the `Azure IoT Edge: Build and Push IoT Edge solution`& `Create Deployment for Single Device` steps. In the Visual Studio Code device explorer I can also see that both my new module and the SampleTemperatureSensor have been created, however only the latter one is showing as running. I also don't receive any messages in the IoT Hub like it did with local debugging.

When I SSH into my Raspberry Pi I can also **not** see my new module running as a Docker container.

Looking at the `deployment.debug.arm32v7.json` I wonder if the docker container cannot be deployed from my local repository `localhost:5000`? Do I perhaps need to deploy the container through ACR for remote debugging?

Comment: Have you deployed your Docker Registry & able to browse pushed images from your dev machine ? What result you see when you run 'sudo iotedge list'? & ' sudo iotedge logs SimulatedTemperatureSensor' ? commands on your Raspberry Pi ? Also visit [Troubleshoot your IoT Edge device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot)

Comment: I'm developing on my PC (that's where the local docker registry also lives), but the runtime is on the Raspberry. I feel like there's a step missing in the guide explaining how to actually get the docker container deployed to a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified localhost as the repository then Docker is going to be looking for that repository on the Raspberry Pi. I'm guessing that's not where it is. You would need to create the repository on your Pi and push your module image to it then it should work. If the repository is already on your Pi then something else must be awry.